# Two PHP scripts interfere and I can't figure why

Tags: php

These two pull out data from two different data bases. It's all good undtil I repeat the first one for a second time (to pull out the count of comments of more than one article), the second script (pulls out the data about vistis to the articles and arranges them by desc. order) stops working (no error, nothing, just doesn't provide an output). I'm no expert (yet) in the PHP so I can't seem to figure what is wrong in this sutuation. Maybe some of you will notice some obvious flaw which makes 'em interfere like that?

1st script (comment count). Just to make it clear: I don't use "define", the second time I use it for a diff. article. It's needed just in the first one to work.):

```
<?php
$id = "1"; //The ID of the page. You can get this from Manage -> Pages.

define('IN_COMMENTICS', '1');
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'comments/includes/db/connect.php');

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `".$cmtx_mysql_table_prefix."comments` WHERE is_approved = '1' AND page_id = '$id'");
$total = mysql_num_rows($query);

echo $total;
?>
```

Second script (counts visits):

```
<?php 

$sql = "SELECT pagename, hits, title FROM counts ORDER BY hits DESC LIMIT 10"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql); 
if(!$res) { 
// oops - exit?  
} 
while(list($page,$hits,$title) = mysql_fetch_row($res)) { 
 echo "<li><a href='$page'>$title</a> $hits</li>"; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: The second script doesn't seem to be establishing a database connection, so I would be surprised if it ever worked?

Comment: It could be a default connection (localhost with guest)

Comment: So, are these scripts both used at some point within the same HTTP request? Or are these command-line PHP scripts?

Comment: The database connection is initiated separately, all good in that sense.

Comment: jokeyrhyme> They are used at the same request of the same page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only thing I could see is that you are using the function `require` to include you database initializing file, **AND** its executed two times which my create problems to causing this issue you are facing.

Perhaps, consider using [require_once](http://php.net/require_once) function which will take care to not load the database initializing file more than one time.

#### To conclude, I would suggest to do the following

Replace this:

```
require ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'comments/includes/db/connect.php');
```

by this:

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'comments/includes/db/connect.php');
```

Comment: You are a wizard sir. Thanks a lot! Tho I wonder why does the other script with an unrelated database was affected by this. (on another page where JUST the scripts of a comment count are used and re-used many times - they all work fine. Just like on the one I had issues with. The things is that - the second script stopped working after I'd put the un-edited comment count code I provided in my question.)..

Comment: Welcome, I'm happy I could be of help to you :) and thanks for accepting the answer, also an upvote would be very welcomed ;)

Comment: Still no can do that (lacking in the reputation deparment). But I will after I level up enough ;)